# Angular Delete row from table using angular services

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to delete a table row using angular services, but unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I have to do that using services because I am using several services with the same control.

```
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.service('allCurrentSettingsService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var allSettings = null;
        this.getList = function () {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings')
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
    }]);


    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'allCurrentSettingsService',
         function ($scope, allCurrentSettingsService) {

             $scope.allSettings = '';
             allCurrentSettingsService.getList().then(function (value) {
                 $scope.allSettings = value;
             });
         }
    ]);

    </script>'
```

And this is my HTML:

`

```
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table border="1">
                <tr ng-repeat="setting in allSettings">
                    <td><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Delete" data-ng-click="DeleteRow(rowValue)" /></td>
                    <td class="hidden">{{setting.SettingID}}</td>
                    <td>{{setting.CompanyName}}</td>
                    <td>{{setting.CustomerName}}</td>
                    <td>{{setting.DocumentName}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

`

Delete method from controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public static void DeleteRecord(int settingID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStringApps))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DeleteCurrentRecord", conn))
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@SettingId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = settingID;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer Updated
>
> I do not recommend to remove a row from your service, it's better if you do that from controller, but for figure out how can remove a row from service see the example.
>
> To Remove From Controller you just convert the service codes as controller like what you see in sample.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, service) {

            $scope.data = [
                { name: "a" },
                { name: "b" }
            ];

            $scope.deleteRow = function (row) {
                $scope.data = service.removeRow(row, $scope.data);
            }
            
            $scope.deleteFromController = function (row) {
                var indexOf = $scope.data.indexOf(row);
                $scope.data.splice(indexOf, 1);
            }

        });

        app.service("service", function ($rootScope) {
            this.removeRow = function (row, data) {
                var indexOf = data.indexOf(row);
                data.splice(indexOf, 1);
                return data;
            }

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h5>click on rows: delete from service</h5>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-click="deleteRow(row)">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h5>click on rows: delete from controller</h5>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-click="deleteFromController(row)">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you explain how to remove the row from the controller.If you include code will be very helpfull

Comment: @user6440175 answer updated, select as answer for others if you get your answer actually :)

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code and added a delete method in the controller. Could you please show me how exactly I can call this method and pass the value to be deleted. Does the method needs to be 'HTTP POST'

Answer (score 0):

From the front end if you want to remove get the index of setting which you want to remove and then use splice.

in the html there has to be an button which initiate the delete operation

your html should be, a rough idea

```
<tr ng-repeat ="setting in allSettings">
    <td>{{setting.SettingID}}</td>
    <!-- other items which you wnted to display-->
    <!-- put one button for delete and use $index to track the index of item to be removed-->
   <td><button ng-click="removeRow($index)">Remove Row</button></td>

</tr>
```

your controller>>

```
$scope.removeRoe = function(index){
//splice will remove the setting row and it will get reflected n the view
  $scope.allSettings.splice(index,1);
}
```

FYI

You need not use service, the removing part has to be done in controller. If you need to hit a backend service(post or delete request) that removes the setting then you need to use angular service